# Update existing value in an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, c#-4.0

I'm trying to update & add values to a ObservableCollection

I have defined the ObservableCollection like this;

```
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, int>> LogSummary
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

In my class I'm subscribing to an event that sends a string containing a letter: A,B,C,D,E or F.

If the string I received already exists in the collection I only want to update the second item(int) that is the count of the string letter I receive.

If i write this code

```
LogSummary.Add(new Tuple<string, int>(_stringFromEvent, intValue));
```

This will just add a new row in the collection so before I use the LogSummary.Add() I need to figure out how to check if the string already exists and if it does it should take the current int value and update it instead of adding a new row to the collection.

Hope you understand my problem!
Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var existing = LogSummary.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Item1 == _stringFromEvent)
if(existing != null)
{
     //update
      LogSummary[LogSummary.IndexOf(existing)] = 
                     new Tuple<string, int>(existing.Item1, intValue);
}
else
{
    //insert new
}
```

Comment: This works but how can I only update the int value in the LogSummary?

Comment: @hijack, you can use the `.Item2` property of the `Tuple` to update the other portion. Please see update above.

Comment: I'm getting the "Property or indexer 'System.Tuple<string,int>.Item2' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" but the property is not set to private..

Comment: sorry, should've tested it, you can just created a new instance of `tuple`